# Correct implementation of determining position in the list

Tags: python, algorithm, implementation, binary-search

I have a list of favourite movies and I'd like to sort them according to my taste from the best movies (have most points) to worst movie (has only 1 point).

Lets say the list contains already 300 sorted movies and you want to determine points for the new movie. You could compare the new movie with every movie in the sorted list or you can utilize the knowledge that the list is sorted.

I tried to implement it as a binary search so every insert (of new movie) has logarithmic complexity.
The binary search implementation was easy for me:

```
def binSearch(lst, number):
  left = 0
  right = len(lst) - 1
  while left <= right:
    middle = left + ((right - left) / 2)
    if number == lst[middle]:
      return True
    else:
      if number < lst[middle]:
        right = middle - 1
      else:
        left = middle + 1
  return False
```

But determining points is quite difficult for me. I'm already debugging it for a few hours and still some errors occur. I changed the implementation many times but nothing helps.
Here is my last solution (maybe the algorithm is in the worse state then it was at the beginning)

```
def determinePoints(lst, new):
  # lst is a list of tuples with movies
  # new is a tuple with new movie (has no point associated yet)
  if not lst: # no movie has points so far
    return 1 #  now exists only one movie with associated points
  newTitle = new[0]
  newGenre = new[1]
  atMost = len(lst)
  atLeast = 0
  while atLeast < atMost - 1: # algorithm doesn't work
                              # if only two movies have associated points
    center = twoPointsCenter(atLeast, atMost)
    (title, genre) = lst[center]
    os.system("clear")
    competitionStrings = [ newTitle, newGenre, "\n" * 10, title, genre ]
    print "\n".join([ x.center(150) for x in competitionStrings ])
    c = getch()
    if c == "j": # new movie is worse than this
      atMost =  center - 1
      if atMost <= 1:
        return 1
    else: # new movie is better than this
      atLeast = center + 1
      if atLeast >= len(lst):
        return max(atLeast, 1)
  return max(twoPointsCenter(atLeast, atMost), 1)

def twoPointsCenter(left, right):
  return left + ((right - left) / 2)
```

Could you correct my solution (or implement it better) to converge and end with the right result?

It should work with lst of lengths from 0, 1, 2, ... etc. It shouldn't return value less than 1. In the list of movies there shouldn't be two movies with the same number of points.

When the function `determinePoints` returns points, I will update the database for this movie and increment points by 1 for each movie with >= points than this new movie.

Thank you

Comment: Why not just use the Python `bisect` module for your binary search?

Comment: @Amber Binary search is only for understanding better the question. Problem is with `determinePoints` and you are free to use whatever you want for correct solution.

Comment: Why not add one to the movies after, and give the current movie the current points?

Comment: What do you mean by points?  Is this some kind of score of how good the movie is?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Don't understand your question.

Comment: Why can't there be two movies with the same number of points? It's a bit of an arbitrary constraint, but its implication is that you can ignore the points altogether and look only at the element ordering when inserting a new movie. And what should happen if you insert a movie between two movies whose score difference is 1? Should all the  movies with scoring greater than or equal to the second be bumped up by 1 to allow the insertion of the new one? I think this is what @IgancioVazquez-Abrams meant.

Comment: @Nisan.H Points are score and ordering in one database column. If two movies would have the same number of points, none of them would be better than the other. Insertion of new points (score) is described in the question (last sentence, but out of scope of the question, this is already correctly implemented).

Comment: @xralf: So is this homework? I don't see why you are writing your own sorting algorithm otherwise.

Comment: @JoelCornett This is my own idea. I'm out of school. Programming is my hobby. This is not sorting algorithm, you don't sort but interactively determine. You haven't read the question carefully.

Comment: @xralf: Hmmm, not seeing a problem. Based on your description, I gather that the point value of a movie is explicitly determined by its position in the list -- which, if you want the minumum value to be 1, would be index + 1 of the index of the item in the list.  So what's the problem? Do you not know where to insert the movie?

Comment: @xralf: also, I would use `dict`s, not tuples, to store movie data.

Comment: @JoelCornett Problem is in the function `determinePoints`. But can be easily seen if you look at it's implementation. It should stop and return the correct points (score) which are giving the movie the correct place in the sequence. It's not so easy. I play with this for quite a long time.

Comment: @xralf: It seems as if you're trying to combine the movie point assignment algorithm with some sort of output formatting. It's probably a good idea to keep a layer of separation between the data you are working with and the visual output of your algorithm.

Comment: FWIW, the binary *search* is logarithmic but the actual insertion of a new movie is *linear*.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger The user will choose the right position in the list with logarithmic number of steps (according to the amount of movies). He has to do `log2(number_of_ordered_movies)` operations, this is what I thought. But you're right, this is not the complexity (computation time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to better look at the boundary indexes. `len(lst)` is one larger than the maximal index, for example: lists are 0-based. I took the liberty to use 0 as lowest possible score; this will directly give you the position to `lst.insert` at. Also, I couldn't resist and made this a little more PEP 8-like.

You don't need all the corner cases; they just work fine, I think.

```
def determine_points(lst, new):
  # lst is a list of tuples with movies, ranked by how good the movie is
  # new is a tuple with new movie
  # the new movies position is to be determined

  new_title, new_genre = new
  at_most = len(lst)
  at_least = 0
  while at_least < at_most:
    center = (at_least + at_most) // 2
    title, genre = lst[center]
    os.system("clear")
    competition_strings = [new_title, new_genre, "\n" * 10, title, genre]
    print("\n".join(x.center(150) for x in competition_strings))
    c = getch()
    if c == "j": # new movie is worse than this
      at_most = center
    else: # new movie is better than this
      at_least = center + 1
  return at_least
```

**Edit**: I tested with the following code.

```
lst = []
news = [(str(i), str(i)) for i in range(10)]
import random
random.shuffle(news)
for new in news:
    print(lst)
    lst.insert(determine_points(lst, new), new)
print(lst)
```

Comment: The idea with zero is good and seems that this is acceptable, but the sorting behaves no good. It gives wrong result already after sorting 3 movies. Maybe that's because you're always returning `at_least`. I play with this conundrum quite a long time :-)

Comment: I have a feeling I was in this place already too. The movies are not ordered according to the interactive choice.

Comment: Could you give an example where this doesn't work? It seems to work perfectly for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, this was my error, because I forgot to change 1 to 0 in three places. Now it seems to work correctly to 7 movies. I will try the test again if I only looked bad.

Comment: I tested it, but there is still error. Look at [this](http://pastebin.com/jySj11qC) four rounds. I replaced the movie names with people names for simplicity. In fourth round `Alex` is better than `Anne` but there was no possibility of competition between `Alex` and `Anne`.

Comment: You must be testing the wrong code. The fourth round starts with Alex vs. Anne, not Alex vs. Erick. Maybe you still have a "+ 1" somewhere?

Comment: This was again my error. The tuples weren't sorted by points. I will accept it, because I have to goto sleep. But I will test it yet tommorrow. Thanks.

Comment: To sum it up. I made two errors. Index should be from zero (to match points) and lst created from database `select` should be ordered by points. At this point I stopped thinking and was only blindly testing and changing conditions in cycle and return value. I see now that you have nice precise thinking. at_least is approaching at_most and then at_last = at_most and you return arbitrary one of them. That's good to know "when testing input data may be wrong".